# when moving from def this(): to def that(): i cant get the value of widgets in this()

Tags: python, tkinter

so basically i am writing a TKINTER program that look like this:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def gettext():
    yourname = myentry.get()

def this():
    myentry = Entry(root)
    myentry.grid(column=0, row=0)

    mybutton = Button(root, text="Go >>>", command=gettext)
    mybutton.grid(column=0, row=1)
this()
```

When i run the script in IDLE 3.5, i get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Luke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1550, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Luke/Desktop/test.py", line 6, in gettext
    yourname = myentry.get()
NameError: name 'myentry' is not defined
```

it cant read my entry, why is that and is there a way around this?

Comment: Have you heard of scope at all? Why do you think this should work?

Comment: Just ask yourself a question: what would happen if you called `gettext()` before `this()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the nice things about Python is that you can define functions within functions, and these sub-functions will have access to the variables that are defined before your sub-function definition.  So, you can do something like the following:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

# This is not the right place to define this if you want to "see" myentry
# def gettext():
#    yourname = myentry.get()

def this():
    myentry = Entry(root)
    myentry.grid(column=0, row=0)

    # Define it here
    def gettext():
        yourname = myentry.get()

    mybutton = Button(root, text="Go >>>", command=gettext)
    mybutton.grid(column=0, row=1)
this()
```

Now, the function `gettext` exists inside of `this`, and can be used as the command for your button.  This function has `myentry` defined within the scope of `this`.

I think that the answer that Sun Bear gave is more comprehensive for what you want to do, but I think that this should give you an indication for why your specific code does not work in the expected way.

Now, I've just edited your code to define the `gettext` function in the appropriate place, but I should note that your function defined as is has no return value, so it won't have an effect.  So you'll need to change that to do what you want it to do, either returning the `yourname` variable or printing `yourname`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason `myentry` in line 6 is not defined because the `myentry` in `gettext()` and `this()` are not the same variable. They are separate entities, they exist locally only in the functions they are found in.

A very useful approach to get around this, especially you will write more complex code later, is to learn to write your functions within a tkinter.Frame class and learn to use the term `self` to create a link between your widgets and variable that are created in different methods within a class. I recommend you learn to do this as you begin learning tkinter. You can google the terms that you don't understand.

Below is a working code of what you want to achieve. Hope this example helps speed your learning process.

```
from tkinter import *

class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent=parent
        self.this()

    def this(self):
        self.myentry = Entry(self)
        self.myentry.grid(column=0, row=0)

        self.mybutton = Button(self, text="Go >>>", command=self.gettext)
        self.mybutton.grid(column=0, row=1)

    def gettext(self):
        yourname = self.myentry.get()
        print('yourname is ', yourname)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    app = App(root)
    app.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

    root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    app.mainloop()
```